# Two LinearLayouts at same position

Tags: android

I want to add two linear layouts at same position with width same as parent. When I press Button1 linearLayout1 should appear and on Button2 LinearLayout2 should appear. How to do this in android?

Comment: Use fragments, show fragment1 when button 1 is clicked and when button2 is clicked display fragment 2.

Comment: You have many options..one is to put them into a frame layout..another is to use a pager...another is to put them on top of each other and play with visibility gone

Comment: Thankss Johan Sir......but Ranjith Siris there any tutorial for fragments?? I want to use fragments.

Comment: @MayureshPawar In my answer below, I have updated code snippets how it can be implemented using fragments and also tutorials where i learnt fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
First create your_xml_file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And java clas...

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button1,button2;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout1,linearLayout2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourXml);

        button1 = (Button).findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button).findViewById(android.R.id.button2);
        linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout).findViewById(android.R.id.firstLinear);
        linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout).findViewById(android.R.id.secondLinear);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


    }
```

Hope this will help you.Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method setVisibility() in your code, as:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Yess I did this its working thanks..but I want to use fragmentss..How should I do this using fragments?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `Fragment` for task, you can simply use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` / `setVisibility(View.GONE)` ( if other UI elements don't depend on view you'll set GONE)

on `onClick` of buttons. It'll look like this:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yess I did this its working thanks..but I want to use fragmentss..How should I do this using fragments?

Comment: You can read up about fragments from Android Developers following this link - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

and this one - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

You can find many other examples showing how to use fragments with a Google search :)

Comment: (Y)Thanks..hope this wl help me:)

Answer (score 0):

> You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity and reuse a
>   fragment in multiple activities too. You can think of a fragment as a
>   modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives
>   its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the
>   activity is running.

Here's how it can be done using Fragment:

First create a layout file with 2 buttons and a Framelayout, we will write code later to replace the framelayout with the contents in the fragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:id="@+id/bt1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:id="@+id/bt2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
        android:id="@+id/frame"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Next create 2 fragments, for eg FragmentA and fragmentB

```
public class fragmentA extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.l1, container, false); //create a layout here
        // add some code to set some text for eg
        return v;
    }
}
```

Create a second fragment B

```
public class fragmentB extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.l1, container, false); //create a layout here
        // add some code to set some text for eg
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now add the Activity code with 2 buttons, when the button 1 is clicked invoke `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new fragmentA()).commit();`, this will replace the framelayout with the contents of the fragmentA, similaryly when button 2 is clicked invoke `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new fragmentB()).commit();`

Complete code:

```
public class MyFragment extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button bt1,bt2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tt);
        bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bt1:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame, new BlockCallers()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.bt2:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame, new smsSetting()).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

For tutorials refer to this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)(official [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html))